# How to prove $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-a_n) = 0$ iff $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n = \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Given ${a_n}$ is infinite sequence, and $0 < a_n < 1$, how to prove

$$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-a_n) = 0 \text{ if and only if } \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n = \infty$$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To study infinite products, you can consider its logarithm: if $P_n=\prod_{k=1}^n a_k$, then $S_n=\ln(P_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(a_n)$.

Comment: Do you possibly mean something else than $1 < a_n < 1$? I think you mean $-1 < a_n < 1$.

Comment: @T.Bongers Sorry, it should be $0< a_n < 1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950653/show-that-prod-1-pa-n-0-iff-sum-pa-n-infty

Answer (score 8):

Use $1-a_n \leq e^{-a_n}$ for $ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n = \infty \implies \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-a_n) = 0$

For the other direction, define independent uniform random variables $(U_n)_{n\geq 1}$ and $A_n =\{U_n < a_n\}$, then we have $\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}P(A_n^c) = 0$

Use Borel-Cantelli lemma like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933429/how-can-we-apply-the-borel-cantelli-lemma-here#933470) enables to conclude.

For a non-pobabilistic proof, see proof and the first comment [here](http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2008/01/26/convergence-of-infinite-products/)