# How to evaluate this troublesome limit?

Tags: limits

I recently encountered the following limit :

$$\displaystyle\lim_{p\to\infty}\dfrac{c^{(p^2+p)/2}}{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^p‌​(c^k-1)},c>1$$

How can one evaluate it ? (from the comments it can be shown that it *converges* to a real value, but what is its limit ?)

Comment: It's the same as asking for the limit of $$\prod_{k=1}^p \frac{1}{1-c^{-k}}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Is this one a known limit ?

Comment: @Hippalectryon It is known to converge.

Comment: @Hippalectryon The limit is finite, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519656/how-to-prove-prod-i-1-infty-1-a-n-0-iff-sum-i-1-infty-a-n/933489#933489)

Comment: this has something to do with eulers partition theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $c^k-1=c^k(1-c^{-k})$, the formula is:

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1-c^{-k}}$$

The function, the reciprocal of [Euler's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function):

$$f(x)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1-x^k}$$

is the [generating function for the partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Generating_function), and the limit you are asking for is $f\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)$.

There is no known closed formula.