# Independent events and Kolmogorov

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, independence

Suppose we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$, and independent events $(E_n)_n$.

Consider $$M_n = \sum_{k=1}^n I_{E_k}$$ Is it correct to say that by the Kolmogorov $01$ law $M_n$ converges a.e or diverges a.e ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a consequence of Kolmogorive 0-1 law. We can also derive it in the following way.

When $E(\sum_{k=1}^\infty I_{E_k}) < +\infty$, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty I_{E_k}$ is finite almost surely, so $M_n$ converges almost surely.

When $E(\sum_{k=1}^\infty I_{E_k}) = +\infty$, we have

\begin{align}
E e^{-\sum_{k=1}^\infty I_{E_k}} &= E\prod_{k=1}^\infty e^{-I_{E_k}}  \\
&= \prod_{k=1}^\infty Ee^{-I_{E_k}}  \\
&= \prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-P(E_k) + e^{-1}P(E_k))\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^\infty(1 - (1-e^{-1})P(E_k))
\end{align}

Since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(E_k) = E(\sum_{k=1}^\infty I_{E_k}) = +\infty$, we have $\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1 - (1-e^{-1})P(E_k)) = 0$, (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519656/how-to-prove-prod-i-1-infty-1-a-n-0-iff-sum-i-1-infty-a-n/933489#933489)), i.e. $$E e^{-\sum_{k=1}^\infty I_{E_k}} = 0$$

So $e^{-\sum_{k=1}^\infty I_{E_k}} = 0$ almost surely, i.e. $M_n$ diverges almost surely.

Comment: Petite Etincelle, how to do your last step [without Markov's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2764954) and without Kolmogorov 0-1 Law?

Comment: @BCLC I think it's obvious that $E X=0$ for non negative would lead to $X=0$ almost surely. If you really want all the details, think of the set $\{X \geq \frac{1}{n}\}$, it has to be of zero probability, and X strictly positive is the union of all these sets, thus also of zero probability

Comment: thanks! $ \ \ \ $

Answer (score -1):

A third proof: (First is by Kolmogorov 0-1 Law. Second is Petite Etincelle's answer)

When $E(\sum_{k=1}^\infty I_{E_k}) < +\infty$, same as in Petite Etincelle's answer

When $E(\sum_{k=1}^\infty I_{E_k}) = +\infty$, we have for $A=1$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(|I_{E_k}|\ge A) = +\infty$$

By Kolmogorov 3-Series Theorem, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty I_{E_k} = +\infty$